# How to add external panel on jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried to implement external panel on JQM 1.4.5 but I did'nt success to display it correctly on my web app. [JQM 1.4.5 doc about external panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external-internal/)
My code is written below.

Thanks for helping,
Clément

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
      <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">No text</a>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="contact">
      <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">No text</a>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        some other content
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="a">
 <div class="ui-panel-inner">
  <ul data-role="listview">
   <li data-icon="home">
    <a id="menu-home" href="index.php#home">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li data-icon="user">
    <a id="menu-account" href="#">Account</a>
   </li>
   <li data-icon="gear">
    <a id="menu-settings" href="#">Settings</a>
   </li>
   <li data-icon="mail">
    <a id="menu-contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
    </div><!-- /mypanel -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enhance the panel in java-script. In `$(document).ready` write the following code:

```
$('#mypanel').enhanceWithin().panel();
```